# Calculate excavation volume

Tags: qgis, volume

I have a dem (0.5 x 0.5 m) and a green polygon (vector) representing a 35° inclined plane. I would like to calculate the volume of terrain between the dem and the inclined plane.
So far I have only calculated the areas (m2) along the orange sections by extracting the topographic profiles and plotting them in AutoCad.

[image]

I was thinking of converting the polygon to raster and making a difference between dem and raster polygon with Raster Calculator but I don't know how to assign altitudes to the polygon.

Comment: Have u seen this tutorial: https://www.pointsnorthgis.ca/blog/how-to-calculate-surfacecut-volume-qgis-advanced/ ?

Comment: I have carried out the operations indicated in the tutorial but I cannot work out whether it has considered an inclined plane along the slope (probably not). How can I add this option?